# Pandas: Filter columns in one level

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with a MultiIndex. I want to drop all the column values in level `1` that have value greater than `12`. I can do

```
df.drop([13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20], level=1, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

but that does not remove values greater than 20. Is there a way to limit the values to 12 only?

Answer (score 2):

using `pd.IndexSlice`

```
df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, :12]]
```

consider `df`

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([list('ab'), range(5,30,5)])
df = pd.DataFrame([np.arange(10)], columns=mux)
print(df)

   a              b            
  5  10 15 20 25 5  10 15 20 25
0  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
```

Then

```
df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, :12]]

   a     b   
  5  10 5  10
0  0  1  5  6
```

---

***caveat***
This requires that `df.columns` is sorted.  You may need to sort ahead of time

```
df.sort_index(axis=1).loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, :12]]
```